# AS3/FLASH: restrict textinput to A-Z and space?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textinput

TEXTINPUT/AS3/FLASH:

I'd like to know haw to add the space when restricting. When I restrict to "A-Z" I can't write names with more than 1 word, like "NOGA NET", i.e.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're working on?

Comment: Mine was:

    compTF.restrict = "A-Z ";

Comment: Have you checked the online reference ? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#restrict - It's pretty descriptive about this subject.

Comment: Thanks, prototypical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textfieldInstance.restrict = "A-Z ";
```

Comment: Ups! Sorry for that! And many, many thanks!